# Lists and Dicts in Python classes without specific instantiation are set to incorrect values

Tags: python

I have the following sample code and I am wondering why the object "b" has it's parameters changed when the "append" function should only apply to "a":

```
>>> class A:
...     a = []
...     b={}
...     c=0
...     d="blah: None"
...     e=()
... 
...     # def __init__(self):
...     #     self.blah = []
... 
...     def append(self, t):
...         self.a.append(t)
...         self.b[t] = 1
...         self.c += 1
...         self.d = f"blah: {t}"
...         self.e = (t)
... 
...     @staticmethod
...     def n():
...         gg = A()
...         return gg
... 
... 
... a=A.n()
... b=A.n()
```

I expected the value of b to remain unchanged as I have only instantiated it; however, when I call the "append" function on a it appears to update the Dict and List values for B as well:

```
... a.append(1)
... print(f"B: {b.a}")
... print(f"B: {b.b}")
... print(f"B: {b.c}")
... print(f"B: {b.d}")
... print(f"B: {b.e}")
... 
B: [1]
B: {1: 1}
B: 0
B: blah: None
B: ()
```

Please could someone explain to me why this is happening and how best to avoid the issue?

Comment: All of `a` through `e` are *class attributes*, at least initially, since you assigned them in the class body instead of `.__init__()`.  In the case of `c`, `d`, and `e`, you actually assign new values to them in `.append()`, so they become ordinary instance attributes, with individual values for each instance of the class.  But `a` and `b` simply have their contents modified, so they remain as class attributes, shared by all of the instances.

Comment: Heh. You triggered all the rookie questions all at once. Nice work. Welcome to python!

Comment: `a` is defined directly inside the class, not inside a function, therefore it is a _class attribute_ that is shared among all instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Because those attributes are class' attributes not object attributes.

Class attributes are common for all instances of the given class.

Instead set attributes in the `__init__`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = []
```